# Repeating "a" in a sentence?

Tags: determiners

Which of the following sentences is correct?

1. I saw a dog and a cat on the road
2. I saw a dog and cat on the road

I.e. is it ok for me to omit the second "a" in the sentence, or must I repeat the "a"?

Comment: What's the *exact* context? Most likely if you saw both animals *together* and/or *at the same time*, you wouldn't repeat ***a***. And vice-versa, since that's what other people would normally assume. But you didn't even seem to give any thought to exactly what you might want either version to mean, so I think you're not thinking about this the right way. ***Context is everything.*** And the biggest thing about "context" is nearly always *What do you mean?*

Comment: I was wondering if, generally, the repeated “a” can be taken to be implicit, and thus omitted. I came up with the example off the top of my head, but what if the dog and the cat are not seen at the same time, or if the exact timing doesn't matter? A similar example would be, "She baked a cake and a pizza for the party"--the focus is on the end products rather than the timing of actions.

Comment: Cats and dogs often go together (not just idiomatic [*It's raining cats and dogs!*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/it-s-raining-cats-and-dogs)) But for reasons I can't put my finger on, ***baking a cake and [a] pizza*** just isn't a combination that often occurs. I've just checked, and in all the millions of books indexed by Google, there isn't a single written instance of ***baking [a] cake and [a] pizza*** with either, neither, or both articles. The same with ***baked [a] cake and [a] pizza*** apart from a reference to *storage of the **partially baked** cake and pizza.*

Comment: ...it just occurred to me maybe the two things would be more often baked *in the order they're usually eaten.* But Google Books finds nothing for ***baked / baking [a] pizza and [a] cake*** either. I think maybe people who eat pizza and cake don't do much baking!

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Suppose it was a cake and a _pie_ that she baked? _Cake and pie_ as a combination doesn't sound natural to my ears.

Comment: @KateBunting: Whether and when to repeat or delete the article in "lists" (of 2 or more nouns) is tricky enough to explain to a learner. Note that the *only* example I found when searching Google Books for several relevant sequences was a sentence that starts with ***Cake and pizza** are not products for daily consumption...* - not ***cakes and pizzas.*** So obviously those specific usages are effectively ***uncountable*** (they refer to *substances* rather than *items*), in which context articles wouldn't be used anyway. The same would/could apply with ***pie[s].***

Comment: ...I've watched most *Men in Black* movies more than once. Maybe I'm misremembering, but it seems to me Tommy Lee Jones says ***I love pie*** more than once. Anyway, that one always strikes me as a "slightly unusual" uncountable noun usage, which is why it sticks in my mind!

Comment: Oh haha I'm sorry my examples are rather awkward. I'm a native English speaker and still not entirely clear on when to delete the articles in lists. I learned grammar mostly by reading books and wasn't taught all the specific rules, so I often go by what I feel "sounds" right, but then when I think harder about the technicalities I get confused and come up with these unnatural cases.